# How do I iterate over this Ruby code so that I can dynamically show markers on a map?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, leaflet, maps

I am building a store locator app and I'm trying to populate a map with markers that represent the stores in my database. I have used the Geocoder gem to convert addresses into latitude and longitude and I am using Leaflet.js and the leaflet-rails gem (basically following this tutorial: https://github.com/axyjo/leaflet-rails). I've been able to get the map to show with markers with the following code:

```
<% @stores.each do |store| %>
    <h2><%= link_to store.name, store_path(store) + ': ' + store.address %></h2>
<% end %>

<%= link_to "Add Spaeti", new_store_path %>

<%= map(:center => {
    :latlng => [52.52004797921441, 12.4050235665359283],
    :zoom => 3
  },

  :markers => [
    {  
       :latlng => [ Store.last.latitude, Store.last.longitude ],
       :popup => Store.last.name
    }
  ]
) %>
```

The problem I'm having is getting markers to appear dynamically from the data in my database. I'm relatively new to Ruby and to Rails, so it's proving quite tough. Should I iterate over the lat and lng values with the each method? I've tried doing that, but getting a lot of syntax errors. I'm not even sure what form the last part of the code is in. Is it a nested hash?

Comment: you should show your attempt that's failing and the errors you see

Comment: `markers: Store.all.map { |store| {latlng: [store.latitude,store.longitude], popup: store.name}`. `Store.all` is an [`ActiveRecord::Relation`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html) and [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) is an `Enumerable` method for iterating an object and creating a new `Array` from the responses.

Answer (score 3):

`markers: Store.all.map { |store| {latlng: [store.latitude,store.longitude], popup: store.name}.` is your failing code.

I think your idea is correct, but your missing a closing `}` for the map block. Try:

`markers: Store.all.map { |store| { latlng: [store.latitude, store.longitude], popup: store.name } }`

As for the data structure, it looks like the map method expects a hash (object) where the marker key that should hold an array of marker hashes (objects) which each have an attribute of latlng and popup. The latlng attribute needs to hold an array of the latitude and longitude values, and the popup attribute should hold a string of the data needed to put in the popup.

Comment: Awesome, it works now :) Thanks a bunch for your help.